# Is setPowerState always called after start?

Tags: macos, usb, kernel, driver, power-management

I'm developing a kernel driver for a USB device on OS X.  After adding the `setPowerState` handler, I'm noticing that it's called for a wake event immediately after the `start` method is called.  This happens on OS X 10.6 when I load the driver, and when I plug the USB device in.

The kernel.log shows the iolog entries I'm making on each method call:

```
...(attach device)
MyDriver: Initializing
MyDriver: Probing
MyDriver: Starting
MyDriver: Waking
...(detach device)
MyDriver: Stopping
MyDriver: Freeing
```

Can I expect wakeup to occur after start every time?

If so is it reasonable to put most of my initialization code into the `setPowerState` handler, knowing it will be called after start?

Is this true for OS X 10.4 and 10.5 as well?

Comment: This concerns programming a kernel driver, so it should be on topic for Stack Overflow.  If you disagree, please consider adding a comment when you cast your close vote so I can revise my question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, provide your have your driver is correctly connected to the Power Plane and has correctly initialised Power Managment (see the link below under the **Implementing Basic Power Management** heading.

It is not only reasonable but it is expected. Note that the only initialization code that make not be in `setPowerState` and that is in `start` or elsewhere is stuff that is only loaded the once and has power state handling code for sleep and wake events in `start`.

For more information see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/PowerMgmt/PowerMgmt.html).

The only difference between setPowerState in Mac OS X versions is that in Mac OS X 10.5 and newer, setPowerState is called in its own thread, whilst 10.4 it is called as part of the existing thread.